# Title visually below image, but above semantically

Tags: html, css

I am looking at adding an image along with a title / caption.
I am looking to keep the title above the image semantically, but below it visually, any idea how to do this with CSS and HTML only?

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesgorrie/vRxuB/9/

Baring in mind that the title needs to be able to be dynamic in size, as does the paragraph. The paragraph can be above or below the image semantically, but below the header semantically and visually.

UPDATE: The image size cannot be assumed.
The closest so far I have got is: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesgorrie/vRxuB/23/

Comment: You can add margins and absolute positions [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/C3JC6/). But there must be a better way

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "semantically above". But maybe [this trick](http://jsfiddle.net/bcAsx/) with `:after` helps.

Comment: @pinouchon By semantically above he means that the `h1` is above in the code.

Comment: Unfortunately the reason is SEO reasons so :after wouldn't help. And sticking styles with in the template would be odd. The margins wouldn't work either, as the update says, image size can't be assumed (Sorry I forgot to specify)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you do something like:

```
<figure>
        <img src="yay.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>
                yay!!!
        </figcaption>
</figure>
```

This is perfectly semantic HTML5

Comment: Thanks. Yea, it's all semantic I guess. I am more interested in the order of it. As I want the H1 to display first when no CSS is applied (SEO) but visually, when CSS is applied, at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Your example doesn't place the header above the image in the code but below visually...

Comment: Sorry, not sure where the fiddle went. New one up